# How to call another html page java servlets

Tags: java, jquery, html, servlets

hello i have simple login project using java servlets. i have *index.html* main page, 2 servlets first *Login.java* servlet serving index.html, second *UserInfo.java* servlet i want to be redirected to when submit button is pressed and jquery file with method which posts entered values to Login.java servlet. when i press login button nothing happens. here are source codes

**index.html**

```
Username:<input type="text" id="username_field" value="" class="round_border"/>
Password:<input type="password" id="password_field" value="" class="round_border"/>
<input onclick="login()" type="submit" value="Submit" id="login_button" class="btn" />
```

**login.js**

```
function login(){


    var username = document.getElementById("username_field");
    var password = document.getElementById("password_field");

    var params = {
        username: username.value, 
        password: password.value
    };


    $.post("Login", params, function(data){alert(data);}
            );
}
```

**Login.java**

```
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher  = request.getRequestDispatcher("UserInfo");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

**UserInfo.java**

```
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet UserInfo</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet UserInfo at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
```

Comment: do you get `alert(data);`?

Comment: exactly i get source code in alertbox. btw i removed alert(data) but then nothing happens

Comment: what was actually in that alertbox?

Comment: source code of UserInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the problem is, that you send an [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) call to the server by this line:

```
$.post("Login", params, function(data){alert(data);}
        );
```

if you perform ajax call, your browser wouldn't go to the new page, your server only redirect the ajax call to another servlet. So if you want to redirect after the ajax call, you have to redirect by javascript.

if your loginServlet would send error like this:

**Login.java**

```
if(!password.equals("123456") //check if password is wrong
    out.println("{\"error\": \"wrong password\"}"); //write error to response. notice, we don't need server-redirect, since we will redirect by the client if the error exists
```

in your client you could do something like this:

```
$.post("Login", params, function(data){
            if(!data.error)
                window.location.href = "http://example.com/UserInfo/";
            else
                alert(data.error);
        });
```

the function will be executed if your ajax-call was successfull and will redirect the browser to the UserInfo servlet

Edit: added success-check

Edit2: added print error to response

Comment: it redirects me even if password or username is incorrect or not filled. i wanted servlet to redirect me when username and password are correct.

Comment: of course it will redirect you if the username is wrong. You could send some kind of error as the result and check it before redirection